# IF Condition in Apache 2.4 is always executed

Tags: apache-2.4, conditional

I am trying to load a module based on a condition.
{PHPMODULENAME} is replaced in the config by the AMP Server I am using - so please don't get confused.

```
<If "'{PHPMODULENAME}' == 'php8_module'">
    LoadModule module1 "..."
</If>
<Else>
    LoadModule module2 "..."
</Else>
```

If the condition is true it should load module1 - because **only then the module1 is available** and module2 isn't. And vice versa.

However when I try to start Apache, it throws an error, because either module1 or module2 is missing. I know that - that's why I add the IF condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache httpd provides a specific conditional  to test for the presence of a module :

The [`< IfModule >`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#ifmodule) directive:

> **Description**: Encloses directives that are processed conditional on the presence or absence of a specific module
> **Syntax**: `<IfModule [!]module-file|module-identifier> ... </IfModule>`

Comment: I was about to post the same, but I got the impression that the goal is not to check if a module is loaded, but to load a specific module if configured in some kind of external configuration management.

Comment: I added the IFModule directive and now it works. It's strange that the parser rises an error for a missing module within an unresolved IF directive, but accepts if the missing module is listed within an unresolved IFModule. IMHO both should react the same way. Anyway, thank you guys!